# How do I add text to each line with different content in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have the following text :

```
ernestobaltar@yahoo.com:Golden-Ball
amaury.tenaille@epfedu.fr:SilverBall
Inspirit@staplesnet.us:Copper_Ball
Matthewsk@mail.montclair.edu:Encourage
sissleib6930@stu.howardcollege.edu:Not-Engaged
```

And I want to get result:

```
yahoo.com:Email.yahoo.com
epfedu.fr:Email.epfedu.fr
staplesnet.us:Email.staplesnet.us
mail.montclair.edu:Email.mail.montclair.edu
stu.howardcollege.edu:Email.stu.howardcollege.edu
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Find what: `^.+(@.+)(:).+?$`
- Replace with `$1$2Email\.$1`
- Set search mode to Regular expression

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Seems it did balance the @ character. Anyhow it helped me finish it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+@([^:]+):.+$`
- Replace with: `$1:Email.$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  @             # literally @
  ([^:]+)       # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not colon
  :             # a colon
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
:           # a colon
Email       # literally Email
.           # a dot
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't know that the dot can be accepted as any other character. Until now I always though that it must be escaped

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: It must be escaped **inside** the regex, not in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for support